# apxproof package: appendix references not shown?

Tags: bibliographies, appendices, appendix

I want to separate my main text references from my appendix references, and am using the apxproof package for that. I do the following:

```
\usepackage{apxproof}
\begin{document}
I am citing~\cite{randomstuff}.
{\balance
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{references}
 }
\begin{toappendix}
Now I am citing~\cite{randomappendixstuff}
{\balance
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{references}
 }
\end{toappendix}
\end{document}
```

However, this is not working. I get both bibliographies with main text references only instead of them being complete but separated. I already tried removing either of the bibliography commands, but that did not help either. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Out of the box BibTeX doesn't do split bibliographies. So if you have two `\bibliography` commands in your document, both will produce the same output. There are some packages that help you in generating split bibliographies, for example https://ctan.org/pkg/bibtopic, https://ctan.org/pkg/bibunits, https://ctan.org/pkg/multibib, https://ctan.org/pkg/chapterbib, but I'm not quite sure if they can give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to specify multiple `\bibliography` commands. apxproof already creates (by default) a bibliography with references that are in the appendix, independently of the bibliography of the references in the main text. This is done through the `bibunits` package, so you need to run `bibtex` on each separate .aux file (`latexmk` does this automatically).

The following complete example works as intended:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{apxproof}
\begin{document}
I am citing~\cite{randomstuff}.

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{references}

\begin{toappendix}
Now I am citing~\cite{randomappendixstuff}
\end{toappendix}
\end{document}
```